# javafx 2 MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE won't load file

Tags: java, media-player, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to run an flv file in javafx2. My code is the following:

```
Media media = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Darren/workspace/player/src/player/football.flv");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

root.getChildren().add(view);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

player.play();
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\Darren\workspace\player\src\player\football.flv (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have checked out similar posts on here. I have also tried storing the video file in different places and tried loads of different ways of accessing it.

The path to the file is:

`C:\Users\Darren\workspace\player\src\player`

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: I am also having this problem. An answer would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

When working with file paths it is always a good idea to use `getClass().getResource("/PATH/RELATIVE/TO/SRC").toExternalForm()`

In that case your code is going to have to look like this:

```
Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/player/football.flv").toExternalForm());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
player.play();
```

Also it is a good idea to keep a `Resources` folder within you src and segregate files within it. Something like this:

```
├───src/
│   ├───Other Packages/
│   ├───Resources/
│   │   ├───Sound/
.   .   .
.   .   .
```

Comment: a relative path (when used as parameter in class.getResource) must not start with a "/" - please read the api doc

Comment: @kleopatra Hi! thank you for the feedback :) Maybe i am misunderstanding the [doc's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-). it states "If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. " I have used it in a couple projects of mine and it worked, without it I would usually get errors.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that even if the file is in resources you still need to give it a better path.
Not sure why this works but it does.

```
String musicFile= "src/main/resources/owin31.wav";

as opposed to

String musicFile= "owin31.wav";
```